# Stray, An body.. and Cannot recover

Tags: javascript, html, w3c, recover

im getting these Errors from W3C

**Line 41, Column 143: Stray end tag body.**

…t1_02.gif','images/Part1_03.gif','images/Part1_04.gif','images/Part1_05.png')">
✉
 **Line 41, Column 143: An body start tag seen but an element of the same type was already open.**

…t1_02.gif','images/Part1_03.gif','images/Part1_04.gif','images/Part1_05.png')">
✉
 **Line 41, Column 143: Cannot recover after last error. Any further errors will be ignored.**

…t1_02.gif','images/Part1_03.gif','images/Part1_04.gif','images/Part1_05.png')">

How can i fix that, And my code is:

http://pastebin.com/g11fz1qP

Answer (score 0):

I have checked you code and this error is occur due to the closing of the tag.
You have not close the `img` tag properly.

The valid tag is:

```
<img src="link_to_image" alt=""/>
```

use the backward slash to end the `img` tag.

Comment: I have done it and it solved the first error with Stray, Now i have the two other left; (Line 41, Column 143: An body start tag seen but an element of the same type was already open.

And

Line 41, Column 143: Cannot recover after last error. Any further errors will be ignored.)

This is the code what have the problem.

<body onLoad="MM_preloadImages('images/Part1_01.gif','images/Part1_02.gif','images/Part1_03.gif','images/Part1_04.gif','images/Part1_05.png')">

Comment: you have used the <body> tag two time. on one page you can use only one time <body> tag. remove the first <body> tag and the end tag of the </body> that you have used before the <body onLoad ....>.

Comment: I Have removed now both, <body> and </body>, but still getting the same problem. http://pastebin.com/JhUPJZ5k

Comment: I think you are newbie in HTML. well no problem. put your script in head tag and close the body tag before the closing of html tag means: </body></html>. this will be at the bottom.

Comment: I have just started to learn about HTML, so yeah, im kinda newbie hehe :P Anyways, i guess i have done it right (http://pastebin.com/ethUxZdn ) <--- Update#2 but it still comes the same problem,

Comment: now this is my last effort and this will give you surely proper solution.

Comment: you have not define the function MM_preloadImages . you should also learn the function(OOPS) to learn the function. in javascript pass the arguments as given in onload function.

Comment: I still dont understand what you mean :/ But what can i do, i mean what should i change in the code to make it work? 

Anyways i have also done a another new docuemnt with that script and bodyonLoad and it works but i dont have any input text, So i dont know, Can it cause it?

Comment: Nevermind! Got it worked somehow, i dont even know what i did but it works!